# numpydoc: Can I omit the type declaration in the docstring when I use type hints?

Tags: type-hinting, pep8, docstring, numpydoc

When using type hints in the function signature, do I need to specify the parameter types in the docstring, too, if I were to comply with numpydoc style?

```
def add(a: float, b: int) -> float:
    """

    Parameters
    ----------
    a
        Fist number.
    b : int
        Second number.

    Returns
    -------
    float
        Result of a + b

    """
    return a + b
```

Is the defintion for `a` in the parameters section sufficient?

Comment: Isn't there anybody who can answer this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present I think the answer is **no** if you want to use  the [`numpydoc`](https://pypi.org/project/numpydoc/) `python` package *directly*. There is an open ticket: https://github.com/numpy/numpydoc/issues/196

I expect any changes will also appear in `numpydoc` [documentation](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html#parameters).

**However**: rendering `docstrings` written in `numpydoc`-like `type`-hinted style *might* work via other packages. Here's what I've found (partly via that `numpydoc` issue):

- [`griffe`](https://mkdocstrings.github.io/griffe) is a `docstring` parser that supports this [`numpydoc-style`](https://mkdocstrings.github.io/griffe/docstrings/#numpydoc-style). That's used by:

  - [`MkDocs`](https://www.mkdocs.org/) via [`mkdocstrings`](https://mkdocstrings.github.io/)
  - [`quarto`](https://quarto.org/) via [`quartodoc`](https://machow.github.io/quartodoc) (see [results-using-type-annotation](https://machow.github.io/quartodoc/get-started/docstring-examples.html#returns-using-type-annotation))
- [`Sphinx`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org) via [`sphinx-autodoc-typehints`](https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-autodoc-typehints/)